# How can I make my Angular Frontend + Spring Boot backend available to all subnets in my network?

Tags: angular, spring, subnet

We have three routers in our home, two are in the basement (Fritzbox with Subnet 192.168.178.X and Asus AX86 with Subnet 192.168.1.X) and the other router is in my room (Honor with Subnet 192.168.3.X). The ASUS and the Honor are connected to the Frizbox router via Ethernet. My Spring Backend Application is running on 192.168.3.203:8080, my Angular Frontend is running on 192.168.3.203:4200. How can a client on the Fritzbox .1.X Subnet connect to my Application?

Answer (score 0):

You must serve your Angular project by a web server like nginx. If you don't have cors problem, you can directly connect to the Spring project, otherwise you must also serve it by web server.